# Spring OAuth2 Google with multiple providers

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I've been googling around trying to find some good documentation on how to implement OAuth2 with Google, closest I've gotten is [this](http://jhasaket.blogspot.no/2014/09/securing-spring-mvc-application-using.html)

It works somewhat, but it doesn't tell me much about how I would go about if I wish to provide multiple authentication providers (e.g. having a username / password, Google and facebook providers). What do I do with refresh tokens? Store them? How are they used in Spring OAuth2/Security?

Anyone know of a guide/example/tutorial/book that would explain this?

Comment: Why do you want to Implement the Google api, are you planning to use calendar, big query, which one, all have their own credential mechanism which can be directly used. I have sample code for Google Calendar, I can post it if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the reply We are Borg.

We use Google at work, and hoped to use the same username / password. So basically just a way to use the google credentials we already have.

Comment: To be honest, I really didn't understand what you mean by your comment, but ok.

Comment: We already have a google account, so we want to use that to authenticate. E.g. like you have on many other registration pages, Sign in with facebook, google or username / password.

Comment: Seems like using Spring Social might be a better approach? Taking a loot at it now.

Comment: This is all to secure REST services though. Should be able to use the REST service from mobile devices, browsers, and desktop applications.

Comment: Google has Google sign-in functionality, but if you are using Spring, then it's Spring-Social to go.